# firebase auth question - can hook email when send change password or find password?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have a questions.
i use firebase auth in my app.
and all of my users will be registering in firebase auth.
if users can't remember their password, they must find theirs
i know firebase auth system that send 'EMAIL' who signed my app up
here's my question.

1. if firebase sends email to user, can i know it?

   - i want user can find password in my app without see email.
2. if i can do this, how can i do this?

   - when i search this problems, i can't find solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to for the application owner to receive a notification when the `sendPasswordResetEmail` is called.

You could of course implement your own notification mechanism, right before calling `sendPasswordResetEmail`. Just keep in mind that this is no guarantee, as malicious users could call the API themselves with your configuration data.